# getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.FileName) says no such file/ directory found

Tags: android

I am making an android app and this line always returns "no such file / directory found".
i certainly have my file in "res/raw/". what is wrong?

here are the images:

file structure:

[image: file structure]

code:
[image: code]

Comment: Maybe it's the wrong name or the filename differs in case? The exception *isn't* lying: it *can't* find said file. This either means it isn't looking where expected, or is told to find something not expected.

Comment: check in Errors wheather the name of the resource is wrong, and check what R you have imprted to your activity.

Comment: Please post your code what you have tried and your directory structure where the file is located.

Comment: thanks.. i posted scrshots. if you want, i'll post my whole code...

Comment: The file extensions seem non-standard. Could you try changing them to .txt if they contain text and try again?

Comment: it worked if i change it into .txt but the file i need must be in .eg format... is there another way to load a file in android?